# Buildship how to set environment variable on project scope

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

We switched for our project from ant to gradle. Now the gradle script looks like this

```
[...]    
def filterFile = System.getProperty('filter.file')
[...]
```

All tasks heavily depend on the environment variable *filterFile*.
We use eclipse (Oxygen.2 Decemeber 2017) with buildship (2.2.1 v20180125-1441)
(which came somehow preinstalled with eclipse? Is that correct that buildship automaticaly comes with eclipse?)

The only way I could make it work is set the variable on task level see screenshot

[image]

The same *DOES NOT work* on project level:
[image]

[image]

When I now remove the setting on the task and put it on the project global setting and execute the very same task it says:

```
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: copyHtml

Filter file null not loaded, some tasks may fail
```

while this works when I set it on the task level.

This are my preference settings for gradle in eclipse:
[image]

Can you please explain of how to set a project wide environment variable.
BTW: I googled the problem and found out about home directory gradle.properties file. But I think this will set project variables and NOT environment variables. As we switched from ant to gradle the gradle build script depends on System.getProperty('filter.file') which might be the wrong way to set this up for gradle but it's the remainigs from the migration from ant so it would be hard for us to change this for every task (as we have plenty of them).

Please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note, that those are [*system properties*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) (a Java thing) instead of [*environment variables*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) (an operating system thing).

#### Why does your current setup not work?

Your second example does not apply project-wide command line arguments, but command line arguments for a Eclipse *Run* configuration, that executes Gradle without any tasks specified. This will cause Gradle to either just run the *configuration phase* without the execution of any tasks, or, if you specified them in your build script, to run the default tasks.

#### How can you solve your problem?

As you can read in the [Gradle documentation on system properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties), you can not only use the command line option `-D` to register a system property, but also the `gradle.properties` file(s) you already mentioned. Just add the `systemProp` prefix to the property name:

```
systemProp.filter.file=hhe-lenovo.dev.properties
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, where does the gradle.properties file need to be located?

Comment: Either in the same directory as the `build.gradle` file (if the properties apply to all users) or in `GRADLE_USER_HOME`, which defaults to a folder `.gradle` in your personal home directory.

Comment: Why does Buildship doesn't provide a possibility to customize the environment, like normal Run Configirations?